# Is there a way to add text to the beginning of tag value?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any way you can add text to the beginning of a tag value like this.

```html
<div id="idName">goes</div>
<script>
  document.getElementById("idName").innerHTML += " here.";
</script>
```

But instead of adding it to the end add it to the beginning. I already tried this.

```html
<div id="idName">goes</div>
<script>
  document.getElementById("idName").innerHTML -= "Text ";
</script>
```

Comment: You don't need to include [tags in titles](http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concat to string at beginning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6094117/concat-to-string-at-beginning)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There must be a lot of ways to perform that, the easiest according to your example could be like this:

```html
<div id="idName">goes</div>
<script>
  document.getElementById("idName").innerHTML = "Text " + document.getElementById("idName").innerHTML + " here.";
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
  var idName = document.getElementById("idName").textContent;
document.getElementById("idName").textContent = " here." + idName;
```

```html
<div id="idName">goes</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save idName innerHTML before add or change it .

```
<div id="idName">goes</div>
<script>
var xidName = document.getElementById("idName").innerHTML;
document.getElementById("idName").innerHTML =  "here " + xidName;
</script>
```