# Add string to copy in clipboard (JS)

Tags: javascript

I want to copy a input text to a clipboard and add before a string.
I use

```
function copyLastColumn() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("oidinput");
  copyText.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
}
```

I want to add the string "DDE-" before the copytext. HOw can I do it?
Thanks Sven

Comment: put `copyText += ‘DDE-‘` before the select?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prepend text to beginning of string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6094117/prepend-text-to-beginning-of-string)

Comment: function copyLastColumn() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("oidinput");
  copyText += 'DDE-';
  copyText.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
}
did not work "copyText.select is not a function"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did here was to set the value of the input (i.e. the text) to your prefix `"DDE-"` + original text, copy it, and then return the input to the original text.

```js
function copyLastColumn() {
  let input = document.getElementById("oidinput");
  let originalText = input.value;
  input.value = "DDE-" + originalText;
  input.select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
  input.value = originalText;
}
```

```html
<body><input type="text" id="oidinput" />
  <button onclick="copyLastColumn()">copy</button>
</body>
```