# Trying to reverse a string by prepending characters

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a function to reverse a string and when I run it I get two errors, one at `tot -= i` showing `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'str' and 'str'`, and at `print(reverse(thestr))`.

However, if I put the `+` in `tot += i`, it works.  How can I solve this, as for my understanding when using `-` it will go in reverse?

```
def reverse(c):
    tot = ''
    for i in c:
        tot -= i
    return tot
thestr = 'This is a Test'
print(reverse(thestr))
```

Comment: The `-` operator is not defined for strings. It's a nice idea to think that `tot -= i` adds `i` to the left of `tot`, but that's not how it works.

Comment: Try `tot = i + tot` instead.

Comment: Maybe you should add `tot` to the right of `i` and assign this back to `tot`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prepend text to beginning of string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6094117/prepend-text-to-beginning-of-string) (oops that's JavaScript, but the answer is the same...)

Comment: "as for my understanding the use the - it will go in reverse" no, that isn't the case, as the error indictes

Comment: Thank you for the information and response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> for my understanding the use the - it will go in reverse

That's incorrect.

To prepend, you can do this:

```
tot = i + tot
```

---

Or, to solve the problem more pythonically, use `reversed()`:

```
def reverse(c):
    tot = ''
    for i in reversed(c):
        tot += i
    return tot
```

Which can then be simplified with `''.join()`:

```
def reverse(c):
    return ''.join(reversed(c))
```

Or simply use a reverse slice:

```
def reverse(c):
    return c[::-1]
```

Comment: The "pythonic" way to reverse a string would be simply `return s[::-1]` which you might as well use if you are going to use `reversed`

Comment: @juanpa Oh yeah, I forgot about that, lol. Added, thanks

Comment: Thank you for the information.  I am learning alot from all of you.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

your code doesn't reverse a string. this will:

```py
def reverse(c):
    l = len(c)
    tot = ''
    for i in range(l):
        tot += c[l - i - 1]
    return tot
thestr ='This is a Test'
print(reverse(thestr))
```

Comment: It's a bit simpler to do `for i in reversed(range(len(c))): tot += c[i]`, but there's no point using indices when you could just do `for i in reversed(c): tot += i` like I wrote in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65030871/4518341).

Comment: using indices is a better place to start IMO. a beginner may be confused how `reversed` works